# String in a function isn't modified in C

Tags: c, string, function, cstring

I'm trying to write a function which receives a string as parameter and then completely modifies it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void updatePEP(char **pep_, int v){
    if((v == 0)){
        //pep_[0] = '1';
        //strncpy(pep_[0],"1", 2);
        strncpy(*pep_,"10", 2);
        //*pep_ = "10";
    }
    else if((v < 0)){
        strncpy(*pep_,"01", 2);
    }
}

int main(){

    char *PEP = "00";
    int i = 0, j = -1;

    printf("%s\n",PEP);

    updatePEP(&PEP,i);
    printf("%s\n",PEP);

    updatePEP(&PEP,j);

    printf("%s\n",PEP);

    return 0;
}
```

I've already searched through the internet and I believe that I'm passing the string as reference correctly, so my doubt is whether I use:

```
pep_[0] = '1';
strncpy(pep_[0],"1", 2);
strncpy(*pep_,"10", 2);
*pep_ = "10";
```

And why?
(But none of them is working, so they may be wrong too...)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run your program step by step.

Comment: `v = 0` is an assignment.You probably want `v == 0`

Comment: `if((v = 0)){`? Good job suppressing the compiler-warning where you should not! Also, string literals are constant literals, even though their type is `char[]`!

Comment: the pep_ (horrible name) is initially set to point to a literal in the .const section of the link (a code page marked as 'read only').  Trying to change that literal is a nono, but is what the code is trying to do.  That is why it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't modify a string literal, it is `const` (read only) by definition, so your program has **undefined behaviour**.

You can use a characters array instead :

```
char PEP[] = "00";
```

And pass this buffer to your function, which can accept this array as a parameter (it will decay to a pointer to the first element).

Also you have a typo in `updatePEP`, you are supposed to check `if (v==0)`:

**Note that the function expects a `char*`** (so you can call it directly with your array), not a `char**`.

```
void updatePEP(char *pep_, int v)
{
    if (v == 0){
        strncpy(pep_,"10", 2);
    }
    else if (v < 0){
        strncpy(pep_,"01", 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 — though I think you should highlight/clarify the change in function prototype a bit more clearly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, sure, just did (feel free to edit !)

Answer (score 1):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. The pointer `PEP` in the `main` functions points to a string literal, and string literals are actually *read-only* arrays of characters. Trying to modify a string literal leads to said undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your original function signature, you could implement the function as:

```
void updatePEP(char **pep_, int v)
{
    if (v == 0)
        *pep_ = "10";
    else if (v < 0)
        *pep_ = "01";
    else               // For symmetry, though not implemented in question
        *pep_ = "00";
}
```

This modifies the pointer that is passed in by address (so pointer to pointer) to point to different string literals.  Your code contained a comment using this notation, so maybe you got this variant working, or maybe you tried it and didn't get it working.

You could then write your main program:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *pep = "00";

    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);
    updatePEP(&pep, +1);
    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);
    updatePEP(&pep,  0);
    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);
    updatePEP(&pep, -1);
    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to modify the string rather than the pointer, then you have a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589300/15168) from [quantdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510483/quantdev) — justifiably accepted (don't change that!) — but it still glosses over the change in the function prototype.  If you're not modifying the pointer as in the code above, then you don't need the extra layer of indirection, but you do need to pass an array and not a string literal.

```
void updatePEP(char *str, int v)
{
    if (v == 0)
        strcpy(str, "10");
    else if (v < 0)
        strcpy(str, "01");
    else               // For symmetry, though not implemented in question
        strcpy(str, "00");
}

int main(void)
{
    char pep[] = "00";

    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);
    updatePEP(&pep, +1);
    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);
    updatePEP(&pep,  0);
    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);
    updatePEP(&pep, -1);
    printf("%p: %s\n", pep, pep);

    return 0;
}
```

Apart from how `pep` is defined, this is the same `main()` function as before.

Note that modifying a string literal leads to undefined behaviour.  Anything may happen; nothing good can be expected.  On many systems, an attempt to modify a string literal will lead to a crash.  On some older systems (mainly archaic ones from the previous millennium), you may be able to modify the string literal, but the modifications remain in effect 'forever' and other code that expects to see `"00"` may instead see `"01"` or `"10"`, probably leading to chaos.  Don't attempt to modify string literals.